# calendarApp: Setting Tag Value

Tags: google-apps-script

I get the error "Argument too large: value" when trying to set a tag for an event (within calendarApp).  Does anyone know if there is a character limit to the value property?  If so, does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit appears to be 1024 characters. I checked it with the following [script](https://script.google.com/d/12iP5Ojlvo5p7bkdkTh03U9aIbyYciBXCcYh5aCWPJvOH1WfSwo2uqOK4/edit?usp=sharing)

[My post on G+ here](https://plus.google.com/102454657796505384036/posts/VnDTeyERiCe)